# How to check for a None object in boost python

Tags: boost, boost-python

I have a function that searches a `std::map` of `boost::python` object elements. I need to search for a particular key value and return the corresponding boost::python object if the object exists in the map, otherwise I need to return a None object. Is there a way for the caller code to identify if the returned object from the function is a None object ?
Below is the code for the search function:

```
namespace bpy = boost::pythono;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

std::map<fs::path, bpy::object> imported_modules;
bpy::object module_exists(fs::path path)
{
    auto it = imported_modules.find(path);
    if (it != imported_modules.end())
    {
        return it->second();
    }
    else
    {

        return bpy::object();// A None object
    }
}
```

Below is how the function is called:

```
bpy::object mod_cached = module_exists(filepath);

if (!mod_cached.is_none())
  { 
    cout << "Module Found" << endl;
  }
```

However, I get the below error when I run my program:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Changing `return it->second();` to `return it->second;` solved the problem.